# Smoothing function with fixed end points (decreasing window size near boundary)

Tags: python, smoothing

I would like either

- a link to a smoothing function from existing library or
- a 'reasonably performant' python function

that performs simple boxcar smoothing but with the catch that it accepts a boundary condition like this:

Suppose an array of length 9, with a rolling window of 5

target  source indices

---

```
  1       1
  2     1 2 3
  3   1 2 3 4 5
  4   2 3 4 5 6
  5   3 4 5 6 7
  6   4 5 6 7 8
  7   5 6 7 8 9
  8     7 8 9
  9       9
```

So the rolling window get smaller near the boundaries, thereby preserving the end point values.

I have looked at:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter1d.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: how should look "an array of length 8, with a rolling window of 3" ?

Comment: That doesn't seem significantly different than 9?  The first sample based of the [1], second [1,2,3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would smooth the valid part first and then fix the boundary conditions. You could apply something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 9, 9)

def rolling_average(x: np.ndarray, n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    boundary_values = n // 2

    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    y[boundary_values: -boundary_values] = np.convolve(x, np.ones(n)/n, mode='valid')

    for i in range(boundary_values):
        y[i] = np.mean(x[:i*2 + 1])
        y[-1 - i] = np.mean(x[-i*2 - 1:])
    return y

print(rolling_average(x, 5))

>>> [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
```

Answer (score -1):

With custom function operating on `numpy` array that starts with generating the main "body" (middle) via rolling slides with [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html), provisions an empty result array including recognized edge size and fills the respective edges at top/bottom sides:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

def roll_window_narrowed(n, win_size):
    """Performs rolling window on an array with the given window size, 
       but narrowing slide at both top/bottom edges.
    """
    core = sliding_window_view(np.arange(1, n + 1), window_shape=win_size)
    c_rows, c_cols = core.shape

    edge_size = win_size // 2 if (win_size % 2) else win_size // 2 - 1
    # provision an empty array including edges
    res_arr = np.empty((c_rows + 2 * edge_size, c_cols), dtype=np.uint32)

    top_edge = core[0]
    for i in reversed(range(0 , edge_size)):
        top_edge = top_edge[:-2]
        res_arr[i, :] = np.pad(top_edge, ((c_cols - top_edge.size) // 2,) * 2)

    res_arr[edge_size: edge_size + c_rows, :] = core

    bottom_edge = core[-1]
    for i in range(res_arr.shape[0] - edge_size, res_arr.shape[0]):
        bottom_edge = bottom_edge[2:]
        res_arr[i, :] = np.pad(bottom_edge, ((c_cols - bottom_edge.size) // 2,) * 2)

    return res_arr
```

---

Sample runs:

```
print(roll_window_narrowed(9, 5))

[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 2 3 0]
 [1 2 3 4 5]
 [2 3 4 5 6]
 [3 4 5 6 7]
 [4 5 6 7 8]
 [5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 7 8 9 0]
 [0 0 9 0 0]]
```

---

```
print(roll_window_narrowed(7, 3))

[[0 1 0]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [3 4 5]
 [4 5 6]
 [5 6 7]
 [0 7 0]]
```

---

```
print(roll_window_narrowed(10, 4))

[[ 0  1  2  0]
 [ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 2  3  4  5]
 [ 3  4  5  6]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 6  7  8  9]
 [ 7  8  9 10]
 [ 0  9 10  0]]
```

Comment: Promising answer, but it seems hard to utalize this directly because the numbers would be used as indices, but zero here used to indicate the absence of a number instead.

Comment: @VictorSavenije, do you expect empty strings instead of `0`s ?

Comment: well, the original request was to perform a rolling smoothing. How would you use your function to do that?

Comment: @VictorSavenije, well, actually and honestly the phrase "rolling smoothing" sounds vague. I've provided the algorithm that builds the crucial internal form

Comment: sorry rolling smoothing is indeed not the correct term. What I mean is rolling mean, moving average, sliding ... etc https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average